# Cloudformation template from existing resources or other possibilities to replicate environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created an ec2 instance and configured it as a target behind my load balancer. I want to convert this entire environment as something that can be deployed repeatedly in automation. I have looked at cloudformation but don't know if it can help me with converting this environment to a cloudformation template. Is there any other way to achieve this. If there is an approach outside of Cloudformation, that's fine too.

PS: I am new to AWS and it's capabilities

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Former2](https://former2.com/).

Former2 allows you to generate Infrastructure-as-Code outputs from your existing resources within your AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

You need an IaC (Infrastructure as Code) tool. Cloudformation is one of them, but there are plenty others. [Terraform](http://terraform.io), [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/) or even the [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at Infrastructure as Code try [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/), [Terraform](http://terraform.io/), you should also look at methods for replacing existing infrastructure. Spinning a fresh set of infrastructure along side the existing one and swapping out in DNS is the most common of approach.